# How can I create empty variables to be filled after the user creates said number?

Tags: java, netbeans, logic

I know I'm explaining it terribly, I'm having a hard time understanding the logic of it also. What I've done is created a way for the user to enter in how many rooms (up to 5) to be created in this calculator. What I don't know how to do, is create the next few lines that act as... placeholders(?) for (up to) 5 rooms. I've put an example below. I apologize, very new to Java.

```
        System.out.print ("Please enter the number of rooms! (Up to 5!) ");

    int roomcount = sc.nextInt();

    String[] places = new String[roomcount];
        for(int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        places[i] = "Place Number: " + i;
        }

        sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("You said that there were " + roomcount + " rooms!");

    System.out.print ("Please enter the types of rooms (up to " +roomcount+ ") that fill up the " + roomcount + " rooms!\n"
            + "(Rooms like Living, Dining, Bedroom1-2, Kitchen, Bathroom, etc!) \n ") ;

    String roomname1 = sc.next();
    String roomname2 = sc.next(); <------ I know these lines are redundant.
                                          I'm just unsure of how to put the idea into action.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Instead of creating it in advance (and by using arrays) you can simply create a `LinkedList` and `add()` to it every time you read another input.

Comment: @alfasin how would I implement that into what I've got here? I'm not familiar with LinkedList or add() I'm sorry!

Comment: If I understood your question, you want to have each `String` in `places[]` to be associated with an other `String` (room type) ?

Comment: Why not read the room names into the elements of `places`?  You've asked how many rooms, gotten the number of rooms in `roomcount`, made space in the array `places` for `roomcount` number of rooms.  Now you're going to ask for `roomcount` number (I'm guessing) of room names and need `roomcount` number of places to store them.  `places` is ready to go, why not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array to add the types of rooms:

```
    String[] types = new String[roomcount];
    for(int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        System.out.print ("Please enter the types of room " + places[i]);
        String roomName = sc.next();
        types[i] = roomName;
        System.out.println("Room name: " + roomName);
    }
```